# Delete repeated rows keeping one closer to another file using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files

```
$cat file1.txt
0105   20   20   95     50
0106   20   20   95     50
0110   20   20   88     60
0110   20   20   88     65
0115   20   20   82     70
0115   20   20   82     70
0115   20   20   82     75
```

If you see the file1.txt, there are repeated values in column-1, which are 0110 and 0115.

So I would like to keep one row only based on the column-5 values, which are closer to corresponding values in a reference file (file2.txt). Here closer means the equal or the nearest value in file2.txt. I don't want to change any value in file1.txt, but just to select one row.

```
$cat file2.txt
0105   20   20   95     50
0106   20   20   95     50
0107   20   20   95     52
0110   20   20   88     65  34
0112   20   20   82     80  23
0113   20   20   82     85  32
0114   20   20   82     70  23
0115   20   20   82     72
0118   20   20   87     79
0120   20   20   83     79
```

So if we compare the two files, we must keep  `0110   20   20   88     65`, as the column-5 entry (i.e. 65) in file1.txt is closer that in reference file (i.e. 65 in file2.txt) and delete the other repeated rows. Similarly we must keep `0115 20 20 82 70` because `70` is closer to `72` and delete other two rows starting with `0115`

Desire output:

```
0105   20   20   95     50
0106   20   20   95     50
0110   20   20   88     65
0115   20   20   82     70
```

I am trying with the following script, but not getting my desire result.

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$5]; next } $5 in a ' file1.txt file2.txt > test.txt
awk '{a[NR]=$1""$2} a[NR]!=a[NR-1]{print}' test.txt
```

My fortran program algorithm is:

```
# check each entries in column-1 in file1.txt with next rows if they are same or not
i.e. for i=1,i++ do  # Here i is ith row
       for j=1,j++ do
if a[i,j] != a[i+1,j]; then print the whole row as it is,
else
# find the row b[i,j] in file2.txt starting with a[i,j]
# and compare the 5th column i.e. b[i,j+5] with all a[i,j+5] starting with a[i,j] in file1.txt 
# and take the differences to find closest one
e.g. if we have 3 rows starting with same entry, then 
we select the a[i,j] in which diff(b[i,j+5],a[i,j+5]) is minumum i=1,2,3
```

Comment: Please be specific about the definition of `closer` e.g. "the average of column 2,3,4,5 is closest to that of the corresponding row in file2.txt".

Comment: Thanks @tshiono. Here closer simply means the nearest or equal value in the file2.txt. It is not the average. Moreover, I don't want to change any value in file1.txt, but just to select one.

Comment: As there are multiple columns, we cannot say nearest or equal without defining some criterion.

Comment: In other words, we cannot *compare* multi-dimensional values such as vectors or complex numbers. We need to reduce it to the comparison(s) of real scalar values.

Comment: Why is `0115 20 20 82 75` 'closer' than `0115 20 20 82 70` to `0115 20 20 82 72`?

Comment: If you can define what 'closer' really means, you might investigate either `sort` or `gawk` sorting to sort the lines and then take the first or last as may be.

Comment: @tshiono. I am so sorry for the confusion. I edited my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    while ((getline line < "file2.txt")>0) {
        split(line, f);
        file2[f[1]] = line;
    }
}
{
    if (!($1 in result)) result[$1] = $0;
    split(result[$1], a);
    split(file2[$1], f);
    if (abs(f[5]-$5) < abs(f[5]-a[5])) result[$1] = $0;
}
END {
    for (i in result) print result[i];
}
function abs(n) {
    return (n < 0 ? -n : n);
}' file1.txt | sort
```